# content_tag with array and ul, li tags - map vs each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have below code in helper:

```
arr = ['one', 'two', 'three']

errors = content_tag :ul do
  arr.map do |msg|
    content_tag :li, msg
  end.join.html_safe
end
```

It works fine, but in the first version I tried `each` instead of `map` and it didn't work. Could anyone explain me why? (`each` version generated just `<ul>onetwothree</ul>`)

Answer (score 3):

This is because [`Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-each) returns the receiver itself on which it was called.But [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map) returns a new array containing the values returned by the block.

```
arr = ['one', 'two', 'three']

arr.each {|i|  i + 'weak' }.join(" ") # "one two three"
arr.map {|i|  i + 'weak' }.join(" ") #"oneweak twoweak threeweak"
```